# If $B$ is worse than $A$ on some inputs, how do their worst-case time complexities compare?

Tags: complexity-theory

You are given two algorithms $A$ and $B$, with worst-case time complexity $f_A(n)$ and $f_B(n)$, respectively.

Assume:

(i) For each $n$ there exists an input $x$ of size $n$ such that the number of steps of algorithm $A$ on $x$ is half the number of steps of $B$ on $x$.

(ii) $f_A(n) = \Omega(h(n))$ for some positive function $h(n)$.

- Is it possible that $f_B(n) = \Omega(h(n))$
- Is it necessary that $f_B(n) = \Omega(h(n))$?

Explain your answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: the first question I said its true since fA(n)>= c*h(n) and we know fA(n)=0.5fB(n) then i can substitue and say 0.5fB(n)>= c*h(n) then in conclusion fB(n) >= 2*c*h(n) so the new constant is (2c) then () = (ℎ()). is that correct ?

Comment: but on the second question I cant come up with a counter example

Comment: Please post your own questions, not questions others ask you. Can you come up with a specific question about this problem other than 'What is the solution'?

Comment: If you write down the definitions then every is actually quite simple.

Comment: The *half* ratio can be absorbed in the hidden constant, so *possible* certainly holds. But  as the relation does not hold for all $x$, the worst-case of $A$ may exceed that of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially asking the following question:

> Suppose that $f(n) \geq g(n)$ for some $n$. Is there a universal constant $C$ such that $\min_n f(n) \geq C \min_n g(n)$?

Hopefully this formulation makes it easier to answer.

Comment: I need help in the second part

Comment: Given my reformulation, I think that you should be able to tackle the problem on your own. It make take time, but that's the only way to learn and get better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider A, B where for problems of size n they both take n log n and n steps respectively, except there is always exactly one problem of size n where A takes n/4 and B takes n/2 steps. Answer your question for these A, B.